# How to use pointers into arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So currently I am still confused in using pointers and reference and I do not know if what I am doing is right. My program is a calculator that stores everything the user inputs. There is an option that the user will be asked if he/she want to view the history and if he/she wants it the program will show all the data he/she inputs.And I need to use pointers and reference in my program but I am still confused on how to use pointers and reference into array
Here is my initialization:

```
int main() {
  int size = 1, fNum[size], sNum[size];
  char oprtn[size], answer;
  ;
  float result[size];
  int *ptrf = &fNum[size];
  int *ptrs = &sNum[size];
  char *ptro = &oprtn[size];
  float *ptrRes = &result[size];
  while (true) {
    cout << "=====CALCULATOR=====\n\n";
    cout << "ENTER TWO NUMBERS:" << endl;
    while (!(cin >> *ptrf >> *ptrs)) {
      system("cls");
      cout << "INVALID INPUT. PLEASE ENTER TWO NUMBERS:\n";
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(2);
    }
    cout << endl;
    do {
      cout << "Choose Operation to be Used: \n"
           << "   +   --- Addition  \n"
           << "   -   --- Subtraction   \n"
           << "   *   --- Multiplication   \n"
           << "   /   --- Division   \n"
           << "   %   --- Remainder   \n";
      cout << "Answer: ";
      cin >> answer;
      cout << endl;
      switch (answer) {
        case '+':
          cout << "ADDITION\n";
          break;
        case '-':
          cout << "SUBTRACTION\n";
          break;
        case '*':
          cout << "MULTIPLICATION\n";
          break;
        case '/':
          cout << "DIVISION\n";
          break;
        case '%':
          cout << "REMAINDER\n";
          break;
        default:
          answer = false;
          system("cls");
          cout << "PLEASE ENTER A VALID ANSWER. CHOOSE BELOW.\n\n";
          cout << "FIRST NUMBER: " << *ptrf << endl;
          cout << "SECOND NUMBER: " << *ptrs;
          cout << endl << endl;
          continue;
      }
    } while (!answer);
    cout << "DO YOU WANT TO TRY AGAIN? (Y / N): ";
    cin >> answer;
    switch (answer) {
      case 'Y':
      case 'y':
        system("cls");
        continue;
      default:
        cout << "VIEW HISTORY? (Y / N): ";
        cin >> answer;
        switch (answer) {
          case 'Y':
          case 'y':
            cout << "HISTORY\n\n";
            break;
          default:
            return 0;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: An array is already a pointer. But, you should really use `std::vector<>` and forget all this stuff.

Comment: "And I need to use pointers and reference in my program" why is that? is this a requirement for your homework? The cases where you really **need** to use raw pointers are quite rare in modern c++. I dont even remember when I had to use one

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis An array is **not** a pointer. It can be used as a pointer when used as a rvalue. The C/C++ wording is that an array can *decay* to a pointer.

Comment: btw your `size` is `1` so all your arrays are really just a single number

Comment: @SergeBallesta being such word-level typical would only suit here to confuse the newbie.

Comment: yes the size is 1 but i will add an increment on the size every time the user want to view history

Comment: cout<<"DO YOU WANT TO TRY AGAIN? (Y / N): ";
 cin>>answer;
  switch(answer){
   case 'Y':
   case 'y':
    system("cls");
    size++
    continue;

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis isnt it the misunderstanding that arrays would be pointers that causes the confusion among newbies?

Comment: you increment `size` (I dont see it in the code) but that wont change the size of the arrays. They are still arrays of size 1

Comment: "And I need to use [...] reference" - you are not using any reference. Also, usually a question goes like "this and that does not work" - have you tested your code? Is there an error happenig? Lastly, `fNum[size]` is no valid standard C++, as `size` is set during runtime (even though it is set to a fixed value). Some compilers will understand, but you shouldn't rely on that. If you have to use raw arrays, use `new` to dynamically allocate storage (better would be to use `std::vector` or `std::array`).

Comment: @ idclev 463035818 actually i have my previous program where i didn't used pointers and it worked properly. it stored all the data and when I want to view history, it shows all the data

Comment: @Aziuth so should it be new size? like that?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/ (maybe ignore the part about `(nothrow)` for the start). Also consider reading other sections of the tutorial, like the previous chapter on pointers.

Comment: _"yes the size is 1 but i will add an increment on the size every time the user want to view history"_: it doesn' work like this. You cannot change the size of a raw array. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I am still new in programming and I do not know what std::vector is used for.

Comment: @newbie I think you should get a good C++ book (emphasis on "good"). You whole code shows major lack of understanding.

Comment: @Jabberwocky  oh thanks for the advice, appreciate it.

Comment: @newbie `std::vector` is a resizeable array. `fNum[size], sNum[size]` *isn't* C++, it's a dialect from your compiler

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid C++ code:

```
  int size = 1, fNum[size], sNum[size];   // wrong: C++ forbids Variable Length Arrays (1)
  char oprtn[size], answer;               // ditto...
  ;
  float result[size];                     // ditto...
  int *ptrf = &fNum[size];         // wrong: this syntax makes ptrf points one past end of array (2)
  int *ptrs = &sNum[size];         // ditto...
  char *ptro = &oprtn[size];       // ditto...
```

(1): VLA are a C language concept. Some compilers (gcc and CLang) allow it *as an extension* but it is useless in C++ because of the containers from the standard library

(2): the idiomatic way to initialize a pointer to the beginning of an array is just `int *ptrf = Num;` When used as a rvalue (in short at the right side of an = sign), an array decays to a pointer to its first element. So it reads `(int *) ptr = &(fNum[0]);`: `ptr` is a pointer to `int` and its initial value is the address of the first element of the array `fNum`

Comment: Nitpick: `int *ptrf = &fNum[size]` declares a *valid* but not *dereferencable* pointer

Comment: @Caleth: The problem is not for `ptrf` to be a valid pointer. It is that OP wanted to initialize it to point to the list...

Answer (score 1):

```
fNum[size]
```

is an array of one integer.

```
int *ptrf = &fNum[size];
```

Is a pointer to one past the last element of this array, therefore it's out of bounds access, this is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Since it only has one element, you declaring it as an array is pointless.

A pointer to the beginning of an array would be:

```
int *ptrf = fNum;
```

Or

```
int *ptrf = &fNum[0];
```

You can then cycle trough the array incrementing the pointer `ptrf++`.

To assing a pointer to a variable:

```
int x;
int *ptr = &x;
```

So the variable declarations and assignments:

```
int size = 1, fNum[size], sNum[size];
char oprtn[size], answer;
float result[size];
int *ptrf = &fNum[size];
int *ptrs = &sNum[size];
char *ptro = &oprtn[size];
float *ptrRes = &result[size];
```

Are the same as:

```
int fNum, sNum;
char oprtn, answer;;
float result; 
int *ptrf = &fNum;
int *ptrs = &sNum;
char *ptro = &oprtn;
float *ptrRes = &result;
```

That said, C++ has mutch nicer data containers you can use like [`std::vector`](https://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

One last note, variable length arrays(`fNum[size]`) are forbidden in C++.

Comment: so, incrementing the address of a variable is the same as incrementing 'i' in 'array[i]'?

Comment: `int *ptrf = &fNum[size];` is not a pointer to the last element, that would be `int *ptrf = &fNum[size - 1];`

Comment: @newbie incrementing a pointer to an address of a given array will make the pointer point to the address of the next element of said array, and yes it has the same effect of incrementing i in array[i].

Comment: so in that case, having a pointer to a n array is useless? like 'int *ptrf = &fNum[size]' ?

Comment: @newbie, it's not useless, this is what pointers are for, like many things in C, there is more than one way to do somenthing, I say C because in C++ the need to use raw pointers is greatly reduced. In C, an example of that need is, for instance, if you want to pass the address of a variable to a function by parameter so it can be modified in the function you must use pointers, otherwise you will be passing copies of the variables.

Comment: @anastaciu so if i will ask the user to input a number, what should I use? cin>>Fnum; or cin>>*ptrf;

Comment: @newbie, you can use either, the result is the same, the inputed value will be assigned to fNum.

Comment: uhmm so in fNum[size] if a assign a pointer it will be *ptrf = &fNum[size], is that right? So i will not do anything to the [size] like putting [*size] or [&size] ?

Comment: @newbie `*ptrf = &fNum[size]` is not the same as `int *ptrf = &fNum[size]` in the latter you are assigning the pointer uppon declaration, the first is not a valid expression. `*ptrf = fNum[size]` is valid and you are assigning to the variable pointed by `ptrf` the value stored in `fNum[size]`, `fNum[size]` will remaiin the same. `ptrf = &fNum[size]` is also valid and you are storing the address of `fNum[size]` in the pointer, thus making the pointer point to `fNum[size]`. I know this can be confusing at first but if you keep at it, in no time you will fully understand how all this works.

Comment: @newbie, in your code `fNum[size]` is an invalid address because the size of the array is 1 and `fNum[size]` is `fNum[1]` this is the second element of a one element array, it's out of bounds. You can still store in `fNum[0]` or `fNum[size-1]` if you prefer, `cin >> fNum[size-1]` or make the pointer to a valid address `int* ptrf = fNum[size-1]` and  `cin >> *ptrf`.

Comment: @anastaciu oh so can I just use an increment on size every time the user want to try again so that it can store values to the array? And should I change [size] to [size -1] instead? Because when I set the value of size to 0, they said that it is invalid for an array to have a size of zero, so I have changed it to 1.

Comment: @newbie you can, but it's tricky the way you have it now, it would involve dynamically allocating and reallocating memory, C++ has the perfect container for that is [std::vector](https://pt.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), this container allows you to add elements to it without worrying with the size, it'll manage it for you. The alternaltive is to have a fixed size array and stop saving values when the array is full.

Comment: @anastaciu so how can I make a storage that don't have a fixed size but it can store any amount of size that the user inputs.

Comment: @newbie, use `std::vector`, there are many tutorials and documentation on how to use this online, it's quite easy, easier than pointers for sure.

Comment: @newbie you're welcome, don't forget to [accept one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you think they address your question.